# Floating label select box in in react native for IOS/Android/Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-web, floating-labels

I am creating application in react native for ios/android and using react native web for web part.
I need select box component with floating label which works on all 3 environments.
I don not want to use any ui library like native base or native paper.

Is there any select box component available which provide this functionality of floating label ?